# Bash - run when function returns a value

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a simple function that calls and endpoint to get a value:

```
get_token() { curl -sf "http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/$1?raw"; }
```

And when you run:

```
echo $(get_token root)
```

It returns a token as a string. Now I want to execute some commands only once, and when this function returns a value because I don't know when the API is up to return the value (almost asynchronous). I thought I can do something like:

```
until [ ! $(get_token root)]; do echo "Hello World!"; done
```

But this runs the echo command infinitely when that function returns the value. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

so... you want to wait until you get a value, and then echo something once?

```
while [[ -z $token ]]; do
    token=$(get_token root)
done
echo "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while [ -z "$token" ]; do
    echo "Hello World!"
    token=$(get_token root)
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations?